# Woocommerce - Hide payment gateway “cod - cash on delivery” and show bacs - Bank Transfer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

Please Guys,

I use two payment gateways on the checkout page:

1° bacs = Bank transfer
2° cod = Cash on Delivery

i need to hide the payment gateway **COD = Cash on Delivery**, If the user has No Admin Profile (!is_user_admin()), || or it's not logged, || ! is_user_logged_in() then hide.

This is the code that i'm using and **it's working.**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_cod_hide' );
  
function bbloomer_cod_hide( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod']) && !is_user_admin() ) {
      unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
   } 
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

The problem is...the payment gateway **bacs = Bank transfer** is also affected and hidden : )

so i tried with this another hook

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'transfer_enable_bacs' );
  
function transfer_enable_bacs( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( isset( $available_gateways['bacs']) && !is_user_admin() ) {
      //unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
   } 
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

But this is not the correct solution. Both payment gateways are hidden.

What am i doing wrong please?
Gratitude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace `is_user_admin` with `current_user_can`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_cod_hide' );
      
    function bbloomer_cod_hide( $available_gateways ) {
       if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
          unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
       } 
       return $available_gateways;
    }
```

`is_user_admin` does not check if the user is an administrator; use `current_user_can()` for checking roles and capabilities.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_admin/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Mo'men Mohamed, but problem still remains.  The payment method **cod** is hidden, but the method **bacs** is also hidden. : )

Comment: Guys,  
Thank you so much for the great Help.  
Both scritps work lika a charm! 
As @Mo'men Mohamed gave me at first the answer, i'll give him the Honer.  
But the same way works normally the Wendell's Script. A Huge Thanks for the great attention!!

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_cod_hide' );

```
function bbloomer_cod_hide( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) || !current_user_can( 'install_themes' ) ) {
      unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
   } 
   return $available_gateways;
}
```